# I want to increment the value of age in a table every 24hours

Tags: c#

I have a column "age" in my database.table 
So here it goes the moment i input a name the age will increment every day so ill get its day old as age
Pls help

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to increment that and moreover no need of storing `Age` as column in your database table since it's a computed/calculated column which can be calculated anytime using the DOB (date of birth) and current date. So while fetching records from table calculate the same and display it

Comment: Dob is the moment they input a data. And i need to display it in the datagridview together with its data